# How can you make a triad gradient in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, gradient

I'm trying to make an icon with three colors (a triad gradient) in different position, like the Apple Music icon (attached) but I'm not sure how to do it correctly.

[image: Apple Music icon]

Answer (score 3):

You can just create a gradient-filled shape layer, then apply a Gradient Overlay Layer Style to that shape.

[image: this is a 3 color gradient]

The Shape layer contains a gradient of 2 colors... then the Layer Style adds the third color.

Right-click/Control-Click the image above and choose `Open image in new tab/window` to see it larger if needed.

Comment: And now you can continue adding additional Gradient Overlays if you're in CC 2015